# What knowledge do players $y_1$ and $y_2$ have exactly in this example for Dependency Quantified Boolean Formula?

Tags: logic

In [1], the authors give the following example to explain how Dependency Quantified Boolean Formulas (DQBF) work:

> As an example for a DQBF, consider the formula
> $∀x_1∀x_2∃y_1(x_1)∃y_2(x_2) : (x_1 ∧ x_2) ≡ (y_1 ≡ y_2)$.
> Here $∀x_1∀x_2∃y_1(x_1)∃y_2(x_2)$ is called
> the quantifier prefix and $(x_1 ∧ x_2) ≡ (y_1 ≡ y_2)$ the matrix of the
> DQBF. This DQBF asks whether there are choices for $y_1$ only depending
> on the value of $x_1$, denoted $∃y_1(x_1)$, and for $y_2$ only depending on $x_2$,
> denoted $∃y_2(x_2)$, such that the Boolean formula after the quantifier
> prefix evaluates to true for all assignments to $x_1$ and $x_2$. (We can interpret this as a game played by $y_1$ and $y_2$ against $x_1$ and $x_2$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ only have
> incomplete information on actions of $x_1$, $x_2$, respectively.) The
> Boolean formula in turn states that the existential variables $y_1$ and
> $y_2$ have to be equal iff $x_1$ and $x_2$ are true. Since $y_1$ can only ‘see’ $x_1$
> and $y_2$ only $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ ‘cannot coordinate’ to satisfy the
> constraint. Thus, the formula is false. Now consider a straightforward
> modification of this DQBF into a QBF with only implicit dependency
> sets. Changing the quantifier prefix into a QBF quantifier prefix
> $∀x_1∃y_1∀x_2∃y_2$ means that $y_1$ may depend on $x_1$, but $y_2$ may depend on $x_1$
> and $x_2$. In that case the formula would be true. Changing the prefix
> into $∀x_2∃y_2∀x_1∃y_1$ has a similar effect.

What would be the exact knowledge of players $y_1$ and $y_2$ here? They must know the Boolean formula (or matrix), but does each player know the dependency of each other player as well, *e.g.* does $y_1$ know that $y_2$ depends on $x_1$ and $x_2$? What else would they (not) know?

---

1. Ge-Ernst, A., Scholl, C., Síč, J., & Wimmer, R. (2022). Solving dependency quantified Boolean formulas using quantifier localization. Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: We prefer that references fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible.  For instance, this helps others with a similar question find this page via search on the title of the paper.  Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!